# Creating a function with Object<?> parameter

Tags: java, generics, methods

I have a main class like this:

```
public class MainClass() {
  public Class<? extends Object> myType;
  // This does not work, but thats what I want:
  public MainClass(Class<? extends Object> type) {
    myType = type;
  }
  public void myMethod(Object<myType> myParameter) {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

And some classes extending this class, for example:

```
public class ChildClass() extends MainClass {
  public ChildClass() {
    super((Class<? extends Object>) String.class);
    // this should be changeable to what ever class then String.class
  }
}
```

How do you create a parent method with a variable class type?
The code `myMethod(Object<myType> obj);` does not work.

Comment: Class `java.lang.Object` does not take type parameters, so `Object<Whatever>` is not going to work.

Comment: myType is variable, not class, I suppose you cannot use it this way. Your code seems quite suspicious to me, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Isn't `? extends Object` the same as just saying `?`

Comment: I guess that `ChildClass` extends `MainClass`, but is missing in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has multiple mistakes:

1. You have parenthesis `()` after you class declarations.
2. You're trying to give generic parameters to Object, which doesn't have generic parameters.

Additionally, you should try declaring a generic type (like `T`) instead of using `?`.  Try this:

```
public class MainClass<T extends Object> {
      public Class<T> myType;

      public MainClass(Class<T> type) {
        myType = type;
      }
      public void myMethod(T myParameter) {
        // Do stuff
      }
}

class ChildClass extends MainClass<String> {
      public ChildClass() {
        super(String.class);
        // this should be changeable to what ever class then String.class
      }
}
```

Also, please note, `T extends Object` is totally redundant, but I left it in since you want it.

Comment: I regret answering this question because it showed a lack of effort with its syntax errors etc. - this is a better answer +1

Comment: Thanks! I didn't knew T could be used for that.

Comment: he is not doing anything with the Class<T> myType, he can remove it and leave default constructors, 
the answer of "Bou Barnouss" is more accurate IMHO

Comment: Not more accurate, just more preferable.  Yes, agreed, you don't need to do anything with Class<T>, but if you make the solution too different from what was tried without much explanation, it doesn't help the one who asked the question as much as it could.

Answer (score 2):

you should do it like this :

```
public class MainClass<T> {
  public void myMethod(T myParameter) {
    // Do stuff
  }
}

public class ChildClass extends MainClass<String> {

}
```

Comment: rather than just showing code, it would be helpful to explain what was wrong with the original and what the difference is.